# Karate UI automation "key" is not defined

Tags: karate

I am using Karate 1.1.0 with chrome driver.
I am trying this special keys as provided in the below documentation to send TAB key to a textbox in our ReactJs app.

- input('body', key.TAB)

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#special-keys
I am seeing the below error message. What am i missing in my setup.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: js failed:
>>>>
01: input('body', key.TAB)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "key" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

classpath:com/mani/sandbox/ui/01.feature:28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. `K` is upper case.

Try:

```
* input('body', Key.TAB)
```